# Restrict access to a single application when logging in from the console without replacing GINA

Tags: windows, authentication

Does anybody know if there is a feasible way on Windows XP to programmatically create and configure a user account so that after logging in from the console (no terminal services) a specific app is launched and the user is "locked" to that app ?

The user should be prevented from doing anything else with the system (e.g.: no ctrl+alt+canc, no ctrl+shift+esc, no win+e, no nothing).

As an added optional bonus the user should be logged off when the launched app is closed and/or crashes.

Any existing free tool, language or any mixture of them that gets the job done would be fine (batch, VB-script, C, C++, whatever)

Answer (score 3):

SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon has two values
UserInit points to the application that is executed upon successful logon. The default app there, userinit.exe processes domain logon scripts (if any) and then launches the specified Shell= application.

By creating or replacing those entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER or in a HKEY_USERS hive you can replace the shell for a specific user.

Once you ahve your own shell in place, you have very little to worry about, unless the "kiosk user" has access to a keyboard and can press ctrl-alt-del. This seems to be hardcoded to launch taskmgr.exe - rather than replacing the exe, you can set the following registry key

```
[SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
Debugger="A path to an exe file that will be run instead of taskmgr.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're building a windows kiosk?

Here's some background in replacing the windows login shell - http://blogs.msdn.com/embedded/archive/2005/03/30/403999.aspx

The above link talks about using IE as the replacement, but any program can be used.

Also check out Windows Steady State - http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/default.mspx